# Core Plot getting the error "Too many arguments to function call"

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, cocoapods

Today i've started to get 2 errors in `CPTAnimationPlotRangePeriod.m`:

[image]

I have tried to clean the project but it doesn't do anything.

It started when i tried to install this: https://github.com/devxoul/JLToast. I have followed all the instruction:

1. `gem install cocoapods --pre`
2. Add this to my Podfile: `pod 'JLToast'`
3. Do `pod install`

This is how my Podfile looks like:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '7.0'


target '[Project name]' do
    pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git', :branch =>    'release-2.0'
    pod 'JLToast'
end
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with [swift] if the error is in Objective-C code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of Cocoapods enabled a new build option that broke Core Plot builds. It's fixed in the latest code. See [issue 138](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/pull/138) for details.

Point your pod file at the repository head rather than a release number.

Comment: Could you actually post the podfile changes required?

Comment: The podfile in the question is fine. It references the head of the `release-2.0` branch. The fix is also on `master`.

Comment: To point to master, use this in your podfile: `pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git'`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than editing your Podfile, you also have the option of fixing the CorePlot code within your project. The required code changes are here: https://github.com/IngmarStein/core-plot/commit/3413d8b7fa382921a918e7801a22e614a17b8bbf